# Highcharts - how to properly update series[0].data and yAxis title of a VUMeter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am preparing a `VU Meter` graph in Highcharts to display an array of values.
These values are displayed one at a time, by choosing an `<OPTION>` of a `<SELECT>`.
I managed to understand how to change the `title` of the graph to match the selected `label` of the `<OPTION>`, but  unfortunately I am a noob and I was not able to properly update the `data` of the `series`.

A *minimal working example* is available on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3nPL/4/). In particular, the following function is fired when the `<SELECT>` is changed:

```
$('#receptorsList0').change(function() {
    var selectedOption = $("#receptorsList0 option:selected");
    var selectedValue = selectedOption.val();
    var selectedText = selectedOption.text();
    alert("i: "+selectedOption+", val: "+selectedValue+", text: "+selectedText);

    // 1. Possible?
    chart.yAxis.setTitle({ text: table[selectedText] + '<br/><span style="font-size:8px">' + selectedText + '</span>' }); 
    // 2. Doesn't work, suggestions? Same with chart.series[0].update(...)
    chart.series[0].setData([selectedValue], true); 
    chart.setTitle({ text: selectedText });
    // 3. Unneeded, right?
    chart.redraw(); 
});
```

My questions are the following:

1. Is the change of the `yAxis`'s `title` supported? This is similar to the command to update the graph's title, but it doesn't work, of course.
2. How am I supposed to change the data? Both `chart.series[0].setData(...)` and `chart.series[0].update(...)` only made the needle to disappear to to stay still. `data` is not properly formatted, maybe? Could you please point me out my mistake?
3. This is unneeded, right (provided that the above works)?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion you may provide!

---

Thanks to [Sebastian Bochan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2021935/sebastian-bochan) who pointed me towards the right direction, I managed to solve the above problems! Please find below the final version of the above function:

```
$('#receptorsList0').change(function () {
    var selectedOption = $("#receptorsList0 option:selected");
    var selectedValue = parseFloat(selectedOption.val());
    var selectedText = selectedOption.text();

    chart.yAxis[0].update({
        title: {
            text : table[selectedText] + '<br/><span style="font-size:8px">'+selectedText+'</span>',
            y : -40
        }
    });
    chart.series[0].data[0].update(selectedValue);
    chart.setTitle({
        text: selectedText
    });
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Yes it is possible by update function on called on axis.
   http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update()
2. update, works on point, so it should be chart.series[0].data[0].update(20);

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me towards the right direction! I will update the question with your suggestions as reference for other people!